# Вывод содержимого Json файла на экран

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Есть `json` файл в котором содержатся сообщения вида

$content[]

```
[{
    "time": "15:58:37",
    "user": "qwe",
    "message": "With []"
},
{
    "time": "15:58:38",
    "user": "qwe",
    "message": "With []"
}]
```

$content

```
{
    "time": "15:59:06",
    "user": "qwe",
    "message": "Without []"
}{
    "time": "15:59:17",
    "user": "qwe",
    "message": "Without []"
}
```

Нужно с этого файла загружать сообщения при переходе на страницу `html`. Выводиться они должны в таблицу, для каждого сообщения новая строка: время, имя, сообщение.

```
<table id="messages">
    <tr class="mess_hide">
        <td class="time"></td>
        <td class="name"></td>
        <td class="message"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Пытаюсь сделать это с помощью `getJSON` но ничего не получается. Что я делаю не так?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON('data/messages.json', function(data) {
    $('#messages').append($('.mess_hide').clone().addClass('mess_tmp').removeClass('mess_hide'));
    $('.mess_tmp>.time').html(data.time);
    $('.mess_tmp>.name').html(data.user);
    $('.mess_tmp>.message').html(data.message);
    $('.mess_tmp').removeClass('mess_tmp');
  });
});
```

Запись в файл

```
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$time = date('H:i:s');
$file = "../data/messages.json";
$json_content = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);
$content = array();

 if(is_array($json_content)) {
    $content = $json_content;
 }
 $content = array("time" => $time, "user" => $user, "message"  => $message);
 file_put_contents($file, json_encode($content, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT),FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: Успешен ли ajax-запрос, что в `data` выводится? У вас там всегда только одно сообщение?

Comment: Услышан. Нет, сообщений может быть и много.

Comment: Т.е. когда у вас там массив, то уже нет никакого `data.time`, а есть `data[0].time` и т.д. Нужно добавить обход по массиву сообщений.

Comment: Попробуйте `$content[] = array("time" => $time, "user" => $user, "message"  => $message);`

Comment: @br3t Не помогло.

Comment: Можете показать текущее содержимое файла messages.json?

Comment: @br3t Добавил в вопрос.

Comment: Не вижу........

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61489/discussion-between---and-br3t).

Comment: В конце вашего json должен быть символ `]`

Comment: @br3t Я понимаю. Я привел вам два примера содержания `messages.json`: Первый  $content[], второй $content. Я немного исправлю вид в вопросе, для понятности.

Comment: `[{
    "time": "15:58:37",
    "user": "qwe",
    "message": "With []"
},
{
    "time": "15:58:38",
    "user": "qwe",
    "message": "With []"
}]`  - в таком виде должно работать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое главное, чтобы даже в случае всего одного сообщения оно было в массиве , т.е. `[{ "time": "13:41:56", "user": "Max", "message": "Hello"}]`

```js
$.getJSON('data/messages.json', callback);
// эмуляция
callback([{ "time": "13:41:56", "user": "Max", "message": "Hello"},{ "time": "13:42:03", "user": "Mike", "message": "Hi"}]);

function callback(respond) {
  for (var i = 0; i < respond.length; i++) {
    var data = respond[i];
    var rowClone = $('.mess_hide').clone().removeClass('mess_hide');
    $('#messages').append(rowClone);
    $('.time', rowClone).html(data.time);
    $('.name', rowClone).html(data.user);
    $('.message', rowClone).html(data.message);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="messages">
    <tr class="mess_hide">
        <td class="time"></td>
        <td class="name"></td>
        <td class="message"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: к сожалению на экран ничего не выводится. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: @МаксимБуяков, добавил эмуляцию вывода. Если не выводится - я бы искал проблему в получаемых данных. Можете привести пример неработающего `messages.json` ?

Comment: Мне кажется, что сообщения в файле не хранятся в массиве. Подскажите, может ли быть такое?Могу добавить в вопрос запись в файл.

Comment: Конечно может. Добавьте.